# Is there a closed form to $a_{n+2}=\frac{(n+1)(n-2)a_{n+1} + (4n+3)a_n - a_{n-1}}{(n+2)(n+1)}$ in terms of $a_0$ and $a_1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

Is there a closed form solution to $$a_{n+2}=\dfrac{(n+1)(n-2)a_{n+1} + (4n+3)a_n - a_{n-1}}{(n+2)(n+1)}$$ that can be written in terms of $a_0$ and $a_1$ given the fact that that $$a_2 = \dfrac{2a_1 - 3a_0}{-2}?$$

I'm doing series solutions to differential equations and I was solving for the coefficients and came to this. I generally can not find a closed form solution in terms of $a_1$ and $a_0$. However, I have seen examples that seem to have cleverly come up with a way to do this. Usually that involves the gamma function somehow by using $\Gamma(n+1) = n\Gamma(n)$ (but they tend to do more that just use the factorial of an integer).

Also, I know that in this case the denominator is $n!$ but beyond that, it just gets messy when I do it.

Any suggestions? I'm hoping that any insight into being able to do this somehow would generalize to a method (or at least tricks) to helping me do this in the future.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Since you know that the denominator is $n!$, it may be useful to make the substitution $c_n=n!\,a_n$. Also, it would be helpful to include the differential equation itself for reference.

Comment: Please don't use displaystyle maths (`\dfrac` triggers this) in question titles. Refer to meta for reasons.

Comment: @Semiclassical I didn't want any assistance with the differential equation itself because this is a homework problem. I was going to still turn in what I had, I just wanted to see if there was a way to go further. I can update this after I turn in my work if you'd like.

Comment: That's fine; in any case, if a reader really wants the diff.eq. they can just work it out from the recurrence relation .

Answer (score 2):

While this does not fully answer the question, one can indeed simplify the problem as per my comment above. Let $c_n:=n!\,a_n$. Then we can deduce a recurrence relation for $c_n$ from $a_n$:

\begin{align}
c_0&=a_0,\quad c_1=a_1,\quad c_2=2a_2=-2a_1+3a_0=-2c_1+3c_0,\\\\
c_{n+2}&=(n+2)!a_{n+2}\\
&=(n+2)!\dfrac{(n+1)(n-2)a_{n+1} + (4n+3)a_n - a_{n-1}}{(n+2)(n+1)}\\
&=(n-2)(n+1)!\,a_{n+1} + (4n+3)n!\,a_n - n!\,a_{n-1}\\
&=(n-2)c_{n+1}+(4n+3)c_n-n c_{n-1}
\end{align}
The coefficients of this recurrence relation still depend on $n$, but as polynomials rather than rational functions in $n$.

Comment: Nice! I've not seen that before. I'm going to try that.